# How to save a macro which does not shift cursor position

Tags: vimrc, macro

I have to do `</^<` a whole lot. So I created a macro: `let @w = '</^<`<kbd>Enter</kbd>`'` (where <kbd>Enter</kbd> is entered via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd>).

But when I run it with `@w` it shifts the cursor down one line - which is NO GOOD because I frequently want to do `.` a few times. So I modified the macro to be `let @w = '</^<`<kbd>Enter</kbd>`k'`

But now it shifts the cursor UP one line! Seems you cannot win! How the heck do you do this and keep the cursor on the same line?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
call setreg('w', "</^<\r", 'c')
```

This issue is explained at `:h :let-@`:

> If the result of {expr1} ends in a <CR> or <NL>, the
> register will be linewise, otherwise it will be set to
> characterwise.

`:let` sets a register ending with CR to linewise; and in a linewise register, a line must always end with `C-j` (at least on linux).

For more info, see [my notes](https://github.com/lacygoill/wiki/blob/master/vim/register.md#when-should-i-avoid-let-to-set--restore-a-register--2).